# BeautifulSoup - get h2 text without class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My code:

```
<div id="title">
<h2>
My title <span class="subtitle">My Subtitle</span></h2></div>
```

If I use this code:

```
title = soup.find('div', id="title").h2.text
print title
>> My title My Subtitle
```

It matches everything. I want to match My title and My Subtitle as 2 different objects:

```
print title 
>> My title
print subtitle
>> My subtitle
```

Any help?

Comment: Added answer which doesnt use 'class'. Maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it without using the class attribute is:

```
h2 = soup.find('div', id="title").h2
subtitle = h2.span.text
title = str(h2.contents[0])
```

The `h2.contents[0]` will return a `NavigableString` object here. Its behavior for print is same as that as the string version of it. If you're only going to use the print statement with it, then the `str()` call won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the subtitle and it's [preceding sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) separately:

```
title = soup.find('div', id="title").h2
subtitle = title.find(class_="subtitle")
print(subtitle.previous_sibling.strip(), subtitle.get_text())
```

Or, you can locate the text node in a non-recursive mode:

```
title = soup.find('div', id="title").h2
print(title.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip(), 
      title.find(class_="subtitle").get_text(strip=True))
```

Both print:

```
(u'My title', u'My Subtitle')
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this example to understand

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#html source
html_source = '''
<div class="test">
     <h2>paragraph1</h2>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
#find h2 tag
print(soup.h2.string)
```

## output

paragraph1

## source

[link](https://pytutorial.com/find-h2-element-python-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<div id="title">
<h2>
My title <span class="subtitle">My Subtitle</span></h2></div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
h2 = doc.select('div#title').h2
print ('title:',h2.firstText())
print ('subtitle:',h2.span.text)
```

Result:

```
title: My title
subtitle: My Subtitle
```